# Get email body from fastapi mail test or mimetext object python

Tags: python, email, fastapi

I am trying to test my outgoing email using FastAPI Mail, I can get the subject, to and from but not the HTML body.

I also managed to get a MIMEText object from it but still have trouble extracting the HTML body from it. I'm sincerely clueless already, is it possible to extract it and if yes how do I extract it??

I also managed to get this after stringifying the MIMEText object

```py
('Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\n'\n 'MIME-Version: 1.0\n'\n 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n'\n '\n'\n 'PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbmc9ImVuIiB4bWxuczp2PSJ1cm46c2NoZW1hcy1taWNy\n'\n 'b3NvZnQtY29tOnZtbCI+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgICA8bWV0YSBjaGFyc2V0PSJ1dGYtOCIgLz4KICAg\n'\n 'IDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9IngtYXBwbGUtZGlzYWJsZS1tZXNzYWdlLXJlZm9ybWF0dGluZyIgLz4KICAg\n'\n 'IDxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IngtdWEtY29tcGF0aWJsZSIgY29udGVudD0iaWU9ZWRnZSIgLz4K\n'\n 'ICAgIDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9InZpZXdwb3J0IiBjb250ZW50PSJ3aWR0aD1kZXZpY2Utd2lkdGgsIGlu\n'\n 'aXRpYWwtc2NhbGU9MSIgLz4KICAgIDxtZXRhCiAgICAgIG5hbWU9ImZvcm1hdC1kZXRlY3Rpb24i\n'\n 'CiAgICAgIGNvbnRlbnQ9InRlbGVwaG9uZT1ubywgZGF0ZT1ubywgYWRkcmVzcz1ubywgZW1haWw9\n'\n 'bm8iCiAgICAvPgogICAgPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0\n'\n 'ZXh0L2h0bWwgY2hhcnNldD1VVEYtOCIgLz4KICAgIDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9ImNvbG9yLXNjaGVtZSIg\n'\n 'Y29udGVudD0ibGlnaHQgZGFyayIgLz4KICAgIDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9InN1cHBvcnRlZC1jb2xvci1z\n'\n 'Y2hlbWVzIiBjb250ZW50PSJsaWdodCBkYXJrIiAvPgogICAgPCEtLVtpZiBtc29dPgogICAgICA8\n'\n 'bm9zY3JpcHQ+CiAgICAgICAgPHhtbD4KICAgICAgICAgIDxvOk9mZmljZURvY3VtZW50U2V0dGlu\n'\n 'Z3MKICAgICAgICAgICAgeG1sbnM6bz0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTpvZmZpY2U6\n'\n 'b2ZmaWNlIgogICAgICAgICAgPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8bzpQaXhlbHNQZXJJbmNoPjk2PC9vOlBp\n'\n 'eGVsc1BlckluY2g+CiAgICAgICAgICA8L286T2ZmaWNlRG9jdW1lbnRTZXR0aW5ncz4KICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICA8L3htbD4KICAgICAgPC9ub3NjcmlwdD4KICAgICAgPHN0eWxlPgogICAgICAgIHRkLAogICAg\n'\n 'ICAgIHRoLAogICAgICAgIGRpdiwKICAgICAgICBwLAogICAgICAgIGEsCiAgICAgICAgaDEsCiAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgaDIsCiAgICAgICAgaDMsCiAgICAgICAgaDQsCiAgICAgICAgaDUsCiAgICAgICAgaDYg\n'\n 'ewogICAgICAgICAgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6ICJTZWdvZSBVSSIsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7CiAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICBtc28tbGluZS1oZWlnaHQtcnVsZTogZXhhY3RseTsKICAgICAgICB9CiAgICAgIDwvc3R5bGU+\n'\n 'CiAgICA8IVtlbmRpZl0tLT4KICAgIDx0aXRsZT5Db25maXJtIHlvdXIgZW1haWwgYWRkcmVzczwv\n'\n 'dGl0bGU+CiAgICA8c3R5bGU+CiAgICAgIDpyb290IHsKICAgICAgICBjb2xvci1zY2hlbWU6IGxp\n'\n 'Z2h0IGRhcms7CiAgICAgICAgc3VwcG9ydGVkLWNvbG9yLXNjaGVtZXM6IGxpZ2h0IGRhcms7CiAg\n'\n 'ICAgIH0KICAgIDwvc3R5bGU+CiAgICA8c3R5bGU+CiAgICAgIC5ob3Zlci1iZy1ibHVlLTYwMDpo\n'\n 'b3ZlciB7CiAgICAgICAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogIzI1NjNlYiAhaW1wb3J0YW50OwogICAg\n'\n 'ICB9CiAgICAgIC5ob3Zlci11bmRlcmxpbmU6aG92ZXIgewogICAgICAgIHRleHQtZGVjb3JhdGlv\n'\n 'bjogdW5kZXJsaW5lICFpbXBvcnRhbnQ7CiAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgQG1lZGlhIChtYXgtd2lkdGg6\n'\n 'IDYwMHB4KSB7CiAgICAgICAgLnNtLXctZnVsbCB7CiAgICAgICAgICB3aWR0aDogMTAwJSAhaW1w\n'\n 'b3J0YW50OwogICAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgICAuc20tcHktMzIgewogICAgICAgICAgcGFkZGluZy10\n'\n 'b3A6IDMycHggIWltcG9ydGFudDsKICAgICAgICAgIHBhZGRpbmctYm90dG9tOiAzMnB4ICFpbXBv\n'\n 'cnRhbnQ7CiAgICAgICAgfQogICAgICAgIC5zbS1weC0yNCB7CiAgICAgICAgICBwYWRkaW5nLWxl\n'\n 'ZnQ6IDI0cHggIWltcG9ydGFudDsKICAgICAgICAgIHBhZGRpbmctcmlnaHQ6IDI0cHggIWltcG9y\n'\n 'dGFudDsKICAgICAgICB9CiAgICAgICAgLnNtLWxlYWRpbmctMzIgewogICAgICAgICAgbGluZS1o\n'\n 'ZWlnaHQ6IDMycHggIWltcG9ydGFudDsKICAgICAgICB9CiAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgQG1lZGlhIChw\n'\n 'cmVmZXJzLWNvbG9yLXNjaGVtZTogZGFyaykgewogICAgICAgIC5kYXJrLW1vZGUtYmctZ3JheS05\n'\n 'OTkgewogICAgICAgICAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogIzFiMWMxZSAhaW1wb3J0YW50OwogICAg\n'\n 'ICAgIH0KICAgICAgICAuZGFyay1tb2RlLWJnLWdyYXktOTg5IHsKICAgICAgICAgIGJhY2tncm91\n'\n 'bmQtY29sb3I6ICMyZDJkMmQgIWltcG9ydGFudDsKICAgICAgICB9CiAgICAgICAgLmRhcmstbW9k\n'\n 'ZS10ZXh0LWdyYXktOTc5IHsKICAgICAgICAgIGNvbG9yOiAjYTlhOWE5ICFpbXBvcnRhbnQ7CiAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgfQogICAgICAgIC5kYXJrLW1vZGUtdGV4dC13aGl0ZSB7CiAgICAgICAgICBjb2xvcjog\n'\n 'I2ZmZmZmZiAhaW1wb3J0YW50OwogICAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgfQogICAgPC9zdHlsZT4KICA8L2hl\n'\n 'YWQ+CiAgPGJvZHkKICAgIGNsYXNzPSJkYXJrLW1vZGUtYmctZ3JheS05OTkiCiAgICBzdHlsZT0i\n'\n 'CiAgICAgIG1hcmdpbjogMDsKICAgICAgd2lkdGg6IDEwMCU7CiAgICAgIHBhZGRpbmc6IDA7CiAg\n'\n 'ICAgIHdvcmQtYnJlYWs6IGJyZWFrLXdvcmQ7CiAgICAgIC13ZWJraXQtZm9udC1zbW9vdGhpbmc6\n'\n 'IGFudGlhbGlhc2VkOwogICAgICBiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiAjZjNmNGY2OwogICAgIgogID4K\n'\n 'ICAgIDxkaXYgc3R5bGU9ImRpc3BsYXk6IG5vbmUiPgogICAgICBDb25maXJtIHlvdXIgZW1haWwg\n'\n 'YWRkcmVzcyB0byBhY3RpdmF0ZSB5b3VyIGFjY291bnQmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OwogICAg\n'\n 'ICAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7\n'\n 'ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsKICAgICAgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAm\n'\n 'Izg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7CiAgICAgICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4\n'\n 'NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OwogICAg\n'\n 'ICAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7\n'\n 'ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsKICAgICAgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAm\n'\n 'Izg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7CiAgICAgICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4\n'\n 'NDc7ICZ6d25qOyAmIzE2MDsmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7CiAgICAg\n'\n 'ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0Nzsg\n'\n 'JiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OwogICAgICAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYj\n'\n 'ODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsKICAgICAgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0\n'\n 'NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7CiAgICAg\n'\n 'ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0Nzsg\n'\n 'JiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OwogICAgICAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYj\n'\n 'ODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsKICAgICAgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmendu\n'\n 'ajsgJiMxNjA7JiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OyAmIzg0NzsgJiM4NDc7ICYjODQ3OwogICAgPC9kaXY+CiAg\n'\n 'ICA8ZGl2CiAgICAgIHJvbGU9ImFydGljbGUiCiAgICAgIGFyaWEtcm9sZWRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPSJl\n'\n 'bWFpbCIKICAgICAgYXJpYS1sYWJlbD0iQ29uZmlybSB5b3VyIGVtYWlsIGFkZHJlc3MiCiAgICAg\n'\n 'IGxhbmc9ImVuIgogICAgPgogICAgICA8dGFibGUKICAgICAgICBjbGFzcz0ic20tdy1mdWxsIgog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgIGFsaWduPSJjZW50ZXIiCiAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOiA2MDBweCIKICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICBjZWxscGFkZGluZz0iMCIKICAgICAgICBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0iMCIKICAgICAgICByb2xlPSJw\n'\n 'cmVzZW50YXRpb24iCiAgICAgID4KICAgICAgICA8dHI+CiAgICAgICAgICA8dGQKICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgY2xhc3M9InNtLXB5LTMyIHNtLXB4LTI0IgogICAgICAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0icGFkZGluZzog\n'\n 'NDhweDsgdGV4dC1hbGlnbjogY2VudGVyIgogICAgICAgICAgPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8YSBocmVm\n'\n 'PSJodHRwczovL21hZmZsbGUuY29tIj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8aW1nCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICBzcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vcmVzLmNsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL3NoZXl6aXNpbHZlci9pbWFnZS91cGxv\n'\n 'YWQvdjE2NTM1NTc4NjUvbWFmZmxsZS1pY29uX3ljb25ybi5wbmciCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB3\n'\n 'aWR0aD0iNzUiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBhbHQ9IllvdXIgTG9nbyIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'IHN0eWxlPSIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgbWF4LXdpZHRoOiAxMDAlOwogICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICB2ZXJ0aWNhbC1hbGlnbjogbWlkZGxlOwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBsaW5lLWhlaWdo\n'\n 'dDogMTAwJTsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYm9yZGVyOiAwOwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIgog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgIC8+CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvYT4KICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ+CiAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'PC90cj4KICAgICAgPC90YWJsZT4KICAgICAgPHRhYmxlCiAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9IgogICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgd2lkdGg6IDEwMCU7CiAgICAgICAgICBmb250LWZhbWlseTogdWktc2Fucy1zZXJpZiwgc3lz\n'\n 'dGVtLXVpLCAtYXBwbGUtc3lzdGVtLCAnU2Vnb2UgVUknLAogICAgICAgICAgICBzYW5zLXNlcmlm\n'\n 'OwogICAgICAgICIKICAgICAgICBjZWxscGFkZGluZz0iMCIKICAgICAgICBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0i\n'\n 'MCIKICAgICAgICByb2xlPSJwcmVzZW50YXRpb24iCiAgICAgID4KICAgICAgICA8dHI+CiAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICA8dGQKICAgICAgICAgICAgYWxpZ249ImNlbnRlciIKICAgICAgICAgICAgY2xhc3M9ImRh\n'\n 'cmstbW9kZS1iZy1ncmF5LTk5OSIKICAgICAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9ImJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6\n'\n 'ICNmM2Y0ZjYiCiAgICAgICAgICA+CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0YWJsZQogICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNs\n'\n 'YXNzPSJzbS13LWZ1bGwiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOiA2MDBweCIKICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICBjZWxscGFkZGluZz0iMCIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0iMCIKICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICByb2xlPSJwcmVzZW50YXRpb24iCiAgICAgICAgICAgID4KICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICA8dHI+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgYWxpZ249ImNlbnRlciIgY2xhc3M9InNtLXB4LTI0\n'\n 'Ij4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRhYmxlCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9Im1h\n'\n 'cmdpbi1ib3R0b206IDQ4cHg7IHdpZHRoOiAxMDAlIgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNlbGxw\n'\n 'YWRkaW5nPSIwIgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPSIwIgogICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgIHJvbGU9InByZXNlbnRhdGlvbiIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPgogICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZAogICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICBjbGFzcz0iZGFyay1tb2RlLWJnLWdyYXktOTg5IGRhcmstbW9kZS10ZXh0LWdy\n'\n 'YXktOTc5IHNtLXB4LTI0IgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0iCiAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogI2ZmZmZmZjsKICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICBwYWRkaW5nOiA0OHB4OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHRl\n'\n 'eHQtYWxpZ246IGxlZnQ7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxNnB4\n'\n 'OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGxpbmUtaGVpZ2h0OiAyNHB4OwogICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNvbG9yOiAjMWYyOTM3OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAi\n'\n 'CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxwCiAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgY2xhc3M9InNtLWxlYWRpbmctMzIgZGFyay1tb2RlLXRleHQt\n'\n 'd2hpdGUiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9IgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgbWFyZ2luOiAwOwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgbWFyZ2lu\n'\n 'LWJvdHRvbTogMzZweDsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiB1\n'\n 'aS1zZXJpZiwgR2VvcmdpYSwgQ2FtYnJpYSwKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'J1RpbWVzIE5ldyBSb21hbicsIFRpbWVzLCBzZXJpZjsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgIGZvbnQtc2l6ZTogMjRweDsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGZvbnQtd2Vp\n'\n 'Z2h0OiA2MDA7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBjb2xvcjogIzAwMDAwMDsKICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgID4KICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBXZWxjb21lLiBZb3UncmUgYWxtb3N0IHRoZXJlLgogICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3A+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxwIHN0eWxlPSJt\n'\n 'YXJnaW46IDA7IG1hcmdpbi1ib3R0b206IDI0cHgiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'IENsaWNrIHRoZSBsaW5rIGJlbG93IHRvIGNvbmZpcm0geW91ciBlbWFpbCBhZGRyZXNzIGFuZAog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGZpbmlzaCB5b3VyIGFjY291bnQgc2V0dXAKICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9wPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8YQogICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODAwMC92MS9hdXRoL2Nv\n'\n 'bmZpcm0tZW1haWw/dG9rZW49ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5\n'\n 'SnpkV0lpT2lKMFpYTjBZWEJ3TG5Ob1pYbDZhVUJuYldGcGJDNWpiMjBpTENKbGVIQWlPakUyTlRV\n'\n 'M05Ea3lOak1zSW1saGRDSTZNVFkxTlRjME56UTJNeXdpYzJOdmNHVWlPaUpsYldGcGJGOWpiMjVt\n'\n 'YVhKdFlYUnBiMjRpTENKcGMzTWlPaUpOWVdabWJHeGxJbjAub1FyX1g0d2NfeDU4WllOX2hkZjN5\n'\n 'S0RhejBtdHNpcUtlRm5SUEhxN3dWRSIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBjbGFzcz0i\n'\n 'aG92ZXItYmctYmx1ZS02MDAiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9IgogICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZGlzcGxheTogaW5saW5lLWJsb2NrOwogICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogIzNiODJmNjsKICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHBhZGRpbmctbGVmdDogMjRweDsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgIHBhZGRpbmctcmlnaHQ6IDI0cHg7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBw\n'\n 'YWRkaW5nLXRvcDogMTZweDsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHBhZGRpbmctYm90\n'\n 'dG9tOiAxNnB4OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgdGV4dC1hbGlnbjogY2VudGVy\n'\n 'OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxNnB4OwogICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZm9udC13ZWlnaHQ6IDYwMDsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgIHRleHQtdHJhbnNmb3JtOiB1cHBlcmNhc2U7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICBjb2xvcjogI2ZmZmZmZjsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHRleHQtZGVj\n'\n 'b3JhdGlvbjogbm9uZTsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgID4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8IS0tW2lmIG1zbwogICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXT48aQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBz\n'\n 'dHlsZT0iCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgbGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6IDI0\n'\n 'cHg7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgbXNvLWZvbnQtd2lkdGg6IC0xMDAl\n'\n 'OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIG1zby10ZXh0LXJhaXNlOiAzMHB4Owog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgID4mIzgyMDI7PC9pCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA+PCEKICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBbZW5kaWZdLS0+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNw\n'\n 'YW4gc3R5bGU9Im1zby10ZXh0LXJhaXNlOiAxNnB4IgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgPkNvbmZpcm0gRW1haWwgQWRkcmVzczwvc3BhbgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ID4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8IS0tW2lmIG1zbwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgXT48aQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0iCiAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgbGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6IDI0cHg7CiAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgbXNvLWZvbnQtd2lkdGg6IC0xMDAlOwogICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgID4m\n'\n 'IzgyMDI7PC9pCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA+PCEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICBbZW5kaWZdLS0+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvYT4KICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRhYmxlCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9\n'\n 'IndpZHRoOiAxMDAlIgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIgog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPSIwIgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgIHJvbGU9InByZXNlbnRhdGlvbiIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPgog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'IDx0ZCBzdHlsZT0icGFkZGluZy10b3A6IDMycHg7IHBhZGRpbmctYm90dG9tOiAzMnB4Ij4KICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGhyCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgc3R5bGU9IgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYm9yZGVyLWJv\n'\n 'dHRvbS13aWR0aDogMHB4OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYm9yZGVy\n'\n 'LWNvbG9yOiAjZjNmNGY2OwogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICIKICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgLz4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwv\n'\n 'dGQ+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgPC90YWJsZT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0ibWFyZ2luOiAwOyBtYXJnaW4tYm90dG9tOiAxNnB4OyBjb2xvcjogIzZi\n'\n 'NzI4MCIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'IEJ1dHRvbiBub3Qgd29ya2luZz8gQ29weSBhbmQgcGFzdGUgdGhlIGxpbmsgYmVsb3cgaW50bwog\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHlvdXIgd2ViIGJyb3dzZXIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDAvdjEvYXV0aC9jb25maXJt\n'\n 'LWVtYWlsP3Rva2VuPWV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUlzSW5SNWNDSTZJa3BYVkNKOS5leUp6ZFdJ\n'\n 'aU9pSjBaWE4wWVhCd0xuTm9aWGw2YVVCbmJXRnBiQzVqYjIwaUxDSmxlSEFpT2pFMk5UVTNORGt5\n'\n 'TmpNc0ltbGhkQ0k2TVRZMU5UYzBOelEyTXl3aWMyTnZjR1VpT2lKbGJXRnBiRjlqYjI1bWFYSnRZ\n'\n 'WFJwYjI0aUxDSnBjM01pT2lKTllXWm1iR3hsSW4wLm9Rcl9YNHdjX3g1OFpZTl9oZGYzeUtEYXow\n'\n 'bXRzaXFLZUZuUlBIcTd3VkUiIHN0eWxlPSJjb2xvcjogIzZiNzI4MCIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICAgID5odHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDAvdjEvYXV0aC9jb25maXJtLWVtYWls\n'\n 'P3Rva2VuPWV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUlzSW5SNWNDSTZJa3BYVkNKOS5leUp6ZFdJaU9pSjBa\n'\n 'WE4wWVhCd0xuTm9aWGw2YVVCbmJXRnBiQzVqYjIwaUxDSmxlSEFpT2pFMk5UVTNORGt5TmpNc0lt\n'\n 'bGhkQ0k2TVRZMU5UYzBOelEyTXl3aWMyTnZjR1VpT2lKbGJXRnBiRjlqYjI1bWFYSnRZWFJwYjI0\n'\n 'aUxDSnBjM01pT2lKTllXWm1iR3hsSW4wLm9Rcl9YNHdjX3g1OFpZTl9oZGYzeUtEYXowbXRzaXFL\n'\n 'ZUZuUlBIcTd3VkU8L2EKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgIDwvcD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICAgICBzdHlsZT0ibWFyZ2luOiAwOyBtYXJnaW4tYm90dG9tOiAxNnB4OyBjb2xvcjog\n'\n 'IzZiNzI4MCIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgIElmIHlvdSBkaWQgbm90IG1ha2UgdGhpcyByZXF1ZXN0LCB5b3UgY2FuIGlnbm9yZSB0aGlz\n'\n 'CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZW1haWwKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg\n'\n 'PC9wPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90ZD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3Ry\n'\n 'PgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RhYmxlPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90ZD4KICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICAgICAgICA8L3RyPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RhYmxlPgogICAgICAgICAgPC90ZD4KICAgICAg\n'\n 'ICA8L3RyPgogICAgICA8L3RhYmxlPgogICAgPC9kaXY+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+\n')
```

The code below gave me that after erroring out

```py
def test_signup_business(client: TestClient, event_loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    """
    Test the /v1/auth/signup?user_type=business endpoint.

    This endpoint should return a 201 status code and a
    JSON response with the full user object.
    """
    fm.config.SUPPRESS_SEND = 1 # This line suppresses the message from sending
    with fm.record_messages() as outbox:
        payload = {
            "username": "test_business",
            "password": "Password123!",
            "email": "blogsedap@gmail.com",
        }
        params = {"user_type": "business"}
        response = client.post("/v1/auth/signup", params=params, json=payload)
        data = response.json()
        assert response.status_code == 201
        assert data["username"] == "test_business"
        assert data["email"] == "blogsedap@gmail.com"
        assert data["user_type"] == "business"
        assert data.get("password") is None
        assert len(outbox) == 1
        assert outbox[0]["subject"] == "Welcome to Mafflle - Verify your email"
        assert (
            outbox[0]["From"] == f"{settings.EMAIL_FROM_NAME} <{settings.EMAIL_FROM}>"
        )
        assert outbox[0]["To"] == data["email"]
        assert str(outbox[0].get_payload()[0]) == "" # (Purposely did this) It errors out and prints the code above this code block
```

> In case I wasn't clear enough... I want to be able to access the HTML body of the email, so I can get the confirmation link and test that too

I figured out it is base64 encoded and when I copy the string and decode it manually I get the HTML, but still, I haven't found a way to get just the base64 string so I can decode it and test it.

I will be glad if anyone can help me

Comment: Do you have any code on what you already have achieved? I am confused on what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to capture the email before it is send to a SMTP server? How are you getting the other elements?

Comment: Yes I do... Let me update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding the body_text works for me:

```py
import base64

payload = outbox[0].get_payload(0).get_payload()
body_text = base64.b64decode(payload).decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

So that didn't work and all I had to do was manually generate a confirmation token and call the `confirm-email` endpoint with the newly generated token.

I trusted the sent token because I generated it the same way as I had done it with the real app... I also made sure it was sending successfully by checking the subject, to and from of the email